# NullException int java.util.List.size() using Retrofit2 when Proguard is enabled

Tags: java, android, retrofit, proguard

I have this null exception everytime i enable Proguard and use Retrofit, to solve it i added my classes which use Retrofit to the Proguard list, example :

```
-keep class com.abohani.example.utils.ban { *; }
```

Even tho i've added it, i'm having the following error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at com.abohani.example.utils.BanUtil$2.onResponse(BanUtil.java:91)
```

This error only happens when Proguard is enabled, when it's disabled no errors at all, the line stated in the error / code sample :

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.API_PATH)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ReApi Api = retrofit.create(ReApi.class);
    Call<Model> Connection = Api.GetList(UID,Key);
    Connection.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            List<BanItem> LatestItems = response.body().GetMain();
            for (int i = 0; i < LatestItems.size(); i++) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }


    });
```

the line 91 is the 'for' loop line, the response is correct and it's not null at all, it's just caused by enabling proguard, and i've already added it to the list and don't know why it's not working .

What causing it? and how to solve this errors without adding classes to the Proguard list, as there're some classes that i can't show its full code, and i must encrypt it using Proguard .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: both Model and BanItem are targeted by the `-keep` instruction?

Comment: All my models are in "model" package, and they're in -keep also .

Comment: I guess the code for those 2 classes could help. Make sure everything that is being parsed is properly kept.

Comment: What classes would you like to provide ? i can provide them, this "size" null thing is annoying me a lot and forcing me to expose my real code to get viewed .

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep class com.abohani.example.utils.** { *; }.
```

Try this adding to proguard and check. Make sure all your models lie under utils package.

Comment: "All my models are in "model" package, and they're in -keep also" plus i can't set all Util classes, as there're some classes i don't want to show its code.